# Rails, how to easily update a Table.field integer with a +1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a ruby/rails trick to easily update a table field type integer with a +1?

I have Invite.clicks

When the user hits the controller, I want to make Invite.click + 1 in the data. Any tricks or do I need to update it manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Is this an ActiveRecord model? If yes, there's an [`increment`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-increment) method:

```
Invite.first.increment!(:click)
```

Comment: The `increment` method doesn't save the record. I would use `update_counters` as suggested by @mu.

Comment: That's why I suggested increment! with a bash.

Comment: I missed the `!` at the end. The `increment!` call will still call `after_save` calls and it is not concurrency safe.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`update_counters`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache.html#method-i-update_counters) to update the value right inside the database:

```
Invite.update_counters(invite_id, :clicks => 1)
```

That translates into a direct SQL call like this:

```
update invites
set clicks = coalesce(clicks, 0) + 1
where id = #{invite_id}
```

The advantage of doing the update inside the database is that you don't have to worry about two updates at the same time fighting each other. You also don't have to pull the whole object out of the database and go through all the usual ActiveRecord stuff if you're just incrementing a counter.